# close old activity with widget

Tags: android, widget, android-activity

I have an activity that can be open with a widget and by pressing the icon. I am wondering how i close the old activity when I press the icon then the home button then the widget?

---

How I want it to work:

1. open activity by pressing icon (show main view)
2. do some stuff in activity(open dialog, change views, etc.)
3. press home button (shows home screen)
4. open activity with widget button (show main view)
5. press back button (**shows home screen**)

How it actually works:

1. open activity by pressing icon (show main view)
2. do some stuff in activity(open dialog, change views, etc.)
3. press home button (shows home screen)
4. open activity with widget button (show main view)
5. press back button (**shows old activity opened with icon**)

---

I have tried using `android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"` `android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"`

`android:launchMode="singleTop"` seems like it should work but it just opens the old activity with the changed view

is there any way to do this without using finish() in onUserLeaveHint()?

Comment: Post your manifest. Also, a question: when testing this did you launch the application for the first time from an IDE (Eclipse, IntelliJ) or from the installer (after installing the APK clicked "open")?

Answer (score 1):

Add the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` to your intent when launch `MainActivity`

Answer (score 0):

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

with

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

Comment: FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK is only for API >= 11